# System.ArgumentException: The encoded string can only be used for a password

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I tried to enter a password to WPF passwordbox and got

> System.ArgumentException: The encoded string can only be used for a
>   password.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Type '********' in text box
    /// </summary>
    public string UIItemEdit1SendKeys = "nAI/+1YbLXAzMC+MylAiumF+gga6bwns";
```

So one more try was

```
Playback.EncryptText("admin")
```

This gave the same exception.
I'm using VS 2013.
It seems that I'm doing very simple thing, entering username and password using Coded UI Test Builder - Recorder. I can record but when run test I got the above argument-exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use the sendkeys method for settting your password, you may get this exception.

Your Test object type, may have a Password attribute. When u set this attribute with an encoded text, it will decrypt automatically

```
// Refer to your Parameter 
uIPasswordEdit.Password = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIPasswordEditPassword;

//Or Simply 
uIPasswordEdit.Password = "nAI/+1YbLXAzMC+MylAiumF+gga6bwns";
```

If you do not see a .Password attribute, you should have a .text attribute. But, please not that u can't use your encrypted string there, u have to give the password itself (Beware, u will compromise security here). It goes like below,

```
//Use the Text Attribute
uIPasswordEdit.Text= "myActualPasswordHere";
```

If nothing works use, the sendkeys as last resort

```
// Click the Password box to gain focus 
Mouse.Click(uIPasswordEdit);
Keyboard.SendKeys("myActualPasswordHere");
```

Comment: Thanks. For me works
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB}", false);
Keyboard.SendKeys("myActualPasswordHere"); I have also tried uIPasswordEdit.Password, but not working in my case.

Comment: Did u try setting the .text property ? what is the exception thrown when u try it ? Pls share ur script & the exception message u get !

Comment: I don't think running on different machines should affect it. Were you able to see the UI field ? Is it possible that the page wasn't loaded completely ? I suggest trying with a non encrypted password to make sure it's not a control specific issues and proceed debugging further.